# Type name as identifier in F#

Tags: f#

I just started to study F# and accidentally wrote this binding

```
let List = 1
```

Now when I try to obtain List methods such as 'filter' I get this error

> error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'filter' is not defined.

Of course using method with full type name like `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List.filter` is still working.

I'm wondering why it is possible to use type name as identifier in F# and how I can set back name List to type List from `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections`.

When I tried to reassign like this

```
type List = Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List<'T>
```

I get

> Error FS0039: The type parameter 'T is not defined.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just rename your let binding from `List` to something sensible - as Gustavo mentioned, your definition is shadowing the core `List` module from F# and there is no way to use `List` to refer both to your integer and to the module. Shadowing core functions will make your code pretty confusing. It's also a good idea to use `camelCase` for let bindings, but that's a matter of taste.

If you insist on shadowing `List`, then you won't be able to call `List.filter` using `List.filter`. If you wanted something shorter, you could define module alias:

```
module FsList = Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List
```

Note that your attempt to do something similar with `List<'T>` does not do the same thing, because functions such as `filter` are in a module named `List` rather than being static members of the type. With this, you can call `filter` using  `FsList.filter`.

Comment: I'm just playing with code using F# Interactive Console in VS. It's not like I realy wanted to have a value named `List`. Somehow it turned out that I could not use list methods anymore. And then I asked this question. Thanks to you and Gustavo I learned new things about F#.

Answer (score 6):

In F# you can redefine almost everything and shadow existing definitions. This applies to both types (well actually types have a different behavior regarding shadowing, they shadow their values as you open the namespaces) and values but not interchangeably since values and type (and also modules) can somehow coexist at the same time in the scope. The compiler will do his best to find out which one is.

You are not forced to, but it's a common good practice in F# not to use let bindings in uppercase.

Regarding your second question, you are using a type parameter in the right side which doesn't exist in the left side of the assignment, it should be:

```
type List<'T> = Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List<'T>
```

But notice that `filter` doesn't belong to the type. It's rather defined in the List module.

Comment: Your expression works but I still can't use code like **List.filter ...** It throws the same error.

Comment: That's because `List` in `List.filter` is the module, not the type.

Comment: Oh! Then after my binding can I somehow access this module methods without full name? I want to use `List.filter` not  `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List.filter`.

Comment: I think the problem is that values have priority against modules, and that kind of makes sense.

Comment: And there is no way to set it back? Like remove this value?

Comment: AFAIK you can not just remove bindings. They get shadowed by other let bindings until they get out of scope. I strongly recommend following the guidelines and avoid Uppercase identifiers in values.